# MobileNet not improving

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to train a MobileNetV2 on a custom dataset, to image Classification task.
Cardinality is 864 images, split in 70%/20%/10%, balanced between the 3 different classes.

Weights are pre-loaded from imagenet, I froze the net and I added to the bottom of the net a GlobalAveragePooling, a Dropout (with 50% drop probability), and a Dense layer with 3 classes and softmax as activation function, since i want the output layer to give me an output like (1,0,0) if the inference image is from the first class, and so on.

- image size: 96x96 (I normalized, too)
- batch_size: 32
- Learning rate: 0.001
- trainable params: 3843
- optimizer: sgd ('adam' doesn't improve my accuracy)
- loss: categorical cross entropy
- metrics: accuracy

Training for 20 epochs gives me these results:
[image: First learning curve]

After that I decided to try some fine-tuning, by freezing only the first 100 layers of the net.
Trained again for 10 epochs, that's what I get:

[image: Learning Curve after fine-tuning]

My net is overfitting, but I don't know why it's happening and what am I expected to do in order to improve my accuracy.

Edit: I also tried increasing dataset images with some source images or even with some data augmentation, up to more than 3K images, but it didn't work out at any rate.

Comment: You should ask at https://datascience.stackexchange.com or https://ai.stackexchange.com thanks!